# Converting variable name to string within a user-defined function that will take the variable as an argument

Tags: r, join, merge, user-defined-functions

I have two dataframes: `df` and `place1`. They have a common variable `Date`. `df` has a variable `Sites` containing various place names including `place1`.

I am building the following function:

```
f <- function(site) {
    merge(subset(df1, Location == deparse(substitute(site))), site, by = 'Date')
}
```

The argument `site` is to take in data frames similarly formatted to `place1` (e.g. `place2`, `place3`, etc.).

Running

```
merge(subset(df1, Location == deparse(substitute(place1))), place1, by = 'Date')
```

is straightforward and performs as expected.

But running `f(place1)` results in a 0-row dataframe. I believe I've narrowed the problem down to the `deparse(substitute(place))` part, but cannot figure out what is wrong with it. Curiously, defining an alternate function `f1` as

```
f1 <- function(site){
    deparse(substitute(site))
}
```

and running `f1(place1)` produces

```
[1] "place1"
```

as expected.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could be the subset function - try replacing subset with `merge(df[df$Location == deparse(substitute(site)),,drop=F],...)`

Comment: so `f <- function(site){
    merge(df1[df1$Location == deparse(substitute(site)),,drop=F], site, by = 'Date') }`

Comment: it's due to the way subset evaluates - e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset

Comment: Problem solved! I've been using subset regularly enough that I never thought to question it. Thanks a ton for the help.